# Cannot Install "tm" package in R macOS Sierra

Tags: r

When calling `install.packages("tm")` I get the following error:

```
> install.packages("tm")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/src/contrib/tm_0.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 526498 bytes (514 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 514 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tm’ ...
** package ‘tm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/BH/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/BH/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c copy.c -o copy.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/BH/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/BH/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c tdm.cpp -o tdm.o
In file included from tdm.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/BH/include/boost/tokenizer.hpp:59:9: error: field of type 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *>' has private constructor
      : first_(c.begin()), last_(c.end()), f_() { }
        ^
tdm.cpp:25:28: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::tokenizer<boost::char_delimiters_separator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >::tokenizer<Rcpp::internal::const_string_proxy<16> >' requested here
        boost::tokenizer<> tok(strings(index));
                           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1239:31: note: declared private here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __wrap_iter(iterator_type __x) _NOEXCEPT : __i(__x) {}
                              ^
In file included from tdm.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/BH/include/boost/tokenizer.hpp:59:28: error: field of type 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *>' has private constructor
      : first_(c.begin()), last_(c.end()), f_() { }
                           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iterator:1239:31: note: declared private here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __wrap_iter(iterator_type __x) _NOEXCEPT : __i(__x) {}
                              ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [tdm.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tm’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/tm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/02/6mkk426d3jd46mg35j577bwc0000gn/T/RtmpHPgAoU/downloaded_packages’
```

My computer runs macOS Sierra. The output of `sessionInfo()` is:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2
```

I didn't have problems installing "slam" as other posts mentioned. I have also tried installing "tm" with the dependencies flag set to TRUE but yields the same output. I installed R via homebrew. I wonder if there are any other steps I can try.

Comment: try install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: I tried that too and got the same error.

Comment: I've got the same issue. It's something with the compiler/libraries, but not quite sure what.

Comment: why is it picking up source repos? I just did it on a system w/o `tm` and it did a full binary install w/o issue. do you need 0.7?

Comment: ok, `tm` 0.7 was literally just released today. the macOS binaries will be available soon. i suggest waiting until then.

Comment: That makes sense, I just tried installing `tm`0.6 from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tm/ and worked.

Comment: What version of `boost` are you running on your system? I think this is an issue with `boost` 1.63.0.

Comment: Yes this machine is running 1.63

Comment: I don't have the energy tonight to make a new `BH` package with 1.63.0 sources but I think that's the core issue (not sure that will fix it of if it needs a downgrade to 1.62.0-1. Glad the old one worked and I'll be curious as to how CRAN makes binaries for this tomorrow/Wed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue. For now, I've installed `tm` 0.6 from the cran.r-project website. This eliminated the compilation errors for me.